# Frequency and hypothesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, chi-squared-test

##### Original Question (Skip to Next Section)

"The results were processed using frequency tables of data obtained and expected data with a confidence level of 90% and with 4 degrees of freedom. To test the hypotheses, the chi-square test was used, obtaining 10.57, compared to the critical chi-square of 7.779. What does it mean?"---OP

##### Edit Including Relevant Info

*From comments section*:

I am reviewing an article. In this research, expected and observed frequencies have been used. I want to know what this type of frequency is used for. Also, why would a 90% confidence interval be used instead of a 95% confidence interval? Finally, what is the purpose or the difference between a chi square and a critical chi to test a hypothesis?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, sorry.

Comment: I am reviewing an article.
In this research, expected and observed frequencies have been used. I want to know what this type of frequency is used for. Also, why would a 90% confidence interval be used instead of a 95%? Finally, what is the purpose or the difference between a chi square and a critical chi to test a hypothesis.

Comment: Those seem like great questions to send back to the author, particularly the issue of the $90\%$ confidence level instead of the usual $95\%$.

Comment: These are things that come up in an intro statistics class. (And why 90%? Because that’s what the authors chose to report.) With all respect, I would invite you to consider informing your editor that someone with different expertise might be better suited to review that article.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I don’t agree that the OP is unqualified to review. The statistics might be a small part of a paper that makes real contributions to medicine (for instance), for which the OP is exceptionally qualified to review, and the OP has questions about a small statistics portion. In that case, I would expect the OP to be an indicator of the statistical level of most readers, so if such concepts are unclear, it’s not unreasonable to explain them in more detail.

Comment: Nevertheless, it might be good if the editor was aware that there is a potential statistical expertise gap there (no shame in that, people can't be experts in everything). If everyone in the process of getting this paper to publication relies on everyone else's statistical expertise and no person with the paper in front of them actually possesses enough to properly review it, there's a lot of potential for problems. On many occasions I have experienced the utter futility of trying to educate a PhD supervisor through the medium of their student; ...

Comment: ... this would present very much the same kind of issues -- a statistically lay referee (for all their subject-matter expertise) cannot be expected to convincingly and accurately convey the sometimes subtle issues involved back to an editor and the original authors, especially if the authors or the editor decide to raise a query in relation to some points. That's not to say this question should not be answered fully and clearly but a few paragraphs of discussion on a website is not likely to be sufficient for the task the OP faces.

Comment: Could someone answer my questions. I am still very new, I know. But I need your opinion so I don't make mistakes. I think there must be a reason why one presents data with obtained and expected frequencies. also, the comparison between the chi square and the critical chi. the sample was 40 people in a company. I consider a very small sample to generalize to a population. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked this question long ago, but just for clarification:

- **Observed frequencies** are the raw frequencies of data observed by the person collecting data.
- **Expected frequencies** are what we would expect the frequency of this data to be
- These frequencies, when subtracted with the chi-square formula, are used to estimate the discrepancy between what we observe and what we expect from the data. If there is a large discrepancy, there is a chance we reject the null hypothesis.
- A 95% confidence interval means that if we were to take 100 different samples and compute a 95% confidence interval for each sample, then approximately 95 of the 100 confidence intervals will contain the true mean value (μ). The only difference with a 90% CI is that it becomes an approximation of 90 out of 100 instead. This in effect gives you a higher chance of rejecting the null hypothesis, whereas making a higher CI (like 99%), makes this test more difficult to pass.
- It seems you are confusing an obtained chi-square value and a critical chi-square value. The chi-square value is what you derive from the chi-square formula, and the critical chi-square is the value you must surpass in order to reject the null hypothesis.